# Success message from Bootstrapious contact form appears on a blank page

Tags: javascript, php, contact-form

I'm building a website using Bootstrap and needed a contact form, so I decided to use the one from [Bootstrapious](https://bootstrapious.com/p/how-to-build-a-working-bootstrap-contact-form). The form works properly and I can receive the messages by email, but the success message appears on a blank page instead of the form page.

I've seen two questions posted here that referred to a similar problem:

[PHP contact form redirects to contact.php with success message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013015/php-contact-form-redirects-to-contact-php-with-success-message)
- This person resolved the problem himself but doesn't really explain how.

[PHP contact form not landing on right page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49262703/php-contact-form-not-landing-on-right-page) - This one had his problem resolved by someone else, but it doesn't seem to work for me (or maybe I just don't understand the solution given).

[Here is my page](http://www.pro-2001.com/nousjoindre.php) if you want to try it to see exactly what it does.

And here is the code (I tried to cut the irrelevant parts, but since I don't really know where the problem is, I might have left a little too much).

HTML page:

```
    <!doctype html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous"></head>

  <body>
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">
<div class="messages"></div>

<div class="controls">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_name">Prénom*</label>
                <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Prénom" required="required" data-error="Votre prénom est requis.">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_lastname">Nom de famille*</label>
                <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Nom de famille" required="required" data-error="Votre nom de famille est requis.">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_email">Courriel*</label>
                <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Courriel" required="required" data-error="Votre adresse courriel est requise.">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_phone">Téléphone</label>
                <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Numéro de téléphone">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_postal">Code postal*</label>
                <input id="form_postal" type="text" name="codepostal" class="form-control" placeholder="Code postal" required="required" data-error="Votre code postal est requis." pattern="[A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z]\s?[0-9][A-Za-z][0-9]">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_message">Message*</label>
                <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Votre message" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Veuillez entrer votre message."></textarea>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Envoyer">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p class="text-muted"><strong>*</strong> Champs obligatoires</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>

          </div>
      </div>
</div>

   <!-- /.container -->

   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../../../assets/js/vendor/jquery-slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="../../../../assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="validator.js"></script>
    <script src="contact.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.css"></script>
```

Contact.php:

```
<?php

$from = 'test <test@test.com>';
$sendTo = 'test <test@test.com>';
$subject = 'Nouveau message';
$fields = array('name' => 'Prénom', 'surname' => 'Nom de famille', 'phone' => 'Téléphone', 'email' => 'Courriel', 'message' => 'Message'); 
$okMessage = 'Le formulaire de contact a bien été envoyé. Merci! Nous vous contacterons dans les plus brefs délais.';
$errorMessage = 'Une erreur s\'est produite en envoyant le formulaire. Veuillez réessayer plus tard.';

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

try
{

if(count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Le formulaire est vide');

$emailText = "Vous avez un nouveau message de votre formulaire de contact\n=============================\n";

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email 
    if (isset($fields[$key])) {
        $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
    }
}

// All the neccessary headers for the email.
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
    'From: ' . $from,
    'Reply-To: ' . $from,
    'Return-Path: ' . $from,
);

// Send email
   mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
$responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}


// if requested by AJAX request return JSON response
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&      strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
$encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo $encoded;
}
// else just display the message
else {
echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

Contact.js:

```
$(function () {

// init the validator
// validator files are included in the download package
// otherwise download from http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator

$('#contact-form').validator();


// when the form is submitted
$('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {

    // if the validator does not prevent form submit
    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        var url = "contact.php";

        // POST values in the background the the script URL
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data)
            {
                // data = JSON object that contact.php returns

                // we recieve the type of the message: success x danger and apply it to the 
                var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                var messageText = data.message;

                // let's compose Bootstrap alert box HTML
                var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';

                // If we have messageAlert and messageText
                if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                    // inject the alert to .messages div in our form
                    $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                    // empty the form
                    $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
})
});
```

Edit 06/03: I've tried Nitin Sharma's suggestion, but it doesn't work. I can redirect to the first page, but then, the success message doesn't appear at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ondrej from Bootstrapious.com here. I am the author of the tutorial.

The problem was well hidden :) It doesn't work because you work with the Slim version of jQuery which doesn't contain AJAX functions that are needed for this to work.

I hope this helps.

Ondrej

Answer (score 0):

With the `action` attribute page redirect to any other page. In your condition, it redirects you to `contact.php` and if you want the page redirect to any other location after submission, just simply change the `contact.php` to the desired page name.

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">
```

change the action to

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="newPage.php" role="form">
```

Comment: Doing that redirects me to the original page after submitting the form, but then, I don't see the success message at all.